# How do i apply TCO(Tail Call Optimiztion) on recursive anonymous Function in ES5

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, ecmascript-6

If I can tco a named recursive function there should be a way to tco anonymous recursive function.If there is a way please explain how to do this below is my recursive function and TCO function.

```
function recursive(length, callback) {

    tco((function (i, sum) {
        var args = arguments;
        if (i > length) {
            console.log("break statement");
            callback(sum)
            return sum
        } else {
            return args.callee(i + 1, sum + i)
        }
    }))(0, 0)
}

function tco(f) {
    var value;
    var active = false;
    var accumulated = [];

    return function accumulator() {
        accumulated.push(arguments);

        if (!active) {
            active = true;

            while (accumulated.length) {
                value = f.apply(this, accumulated.shift());
            }

            active = false;

            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt you can name any code construct a TCO (since it's a compiler/runtime optimisation technique, not something you can code yourself). Your code is tangled, but I'd make a guess it's just some sort of weird "trampoline" instead.

Comment: Why do you think recursion needed named functions? Have a look at the `Y` combinator.

Comment: What does this have to do with ES2015? Btw, all functions are optimised for tailrecursion in a spec-compliant ES6 implementation already, so you don't have to implement anything yourself.

Comment: @Bergi i hope you reconsider the -1 because you guys are not exactly correct in your comments. read my answer

Comment: @AhmadBamieh your answer does not make me or Bergi wrong :-S

Comment: @zerkms it is something you need to account for when you need to optimize your functions, its not a blackbox, its a spec with 4 requirements that you must follow to get the optimization. Bergi said almost the same, that you dont have to implement anything yourself, but again, you have to follow the spec requirements for the optimization. i didnt say youre wrong, just `not exactly correct`.

Comment: @AhmadBamieh well, I am exactly correct: you cannot "apply TCO". TCO is applied by runtime/compiler. That is by definition. You can only put a call into the tail position (hence make it TC-optimisable).

Comment: Sorry guys about my question, my question was on ES5, I was confused Es2015 to be es5. well in es6 s I read somewhere on Internet that tco is internally handled by interpreter, but in es5 I think we manually need to optimize recursions to prevent Max call stack exceeded, Now here comes my question is there a way to optimize recursion using siaf in es5

Answer (score 3):

## Tail Call Optimization

ES6 proposes changes to the tail-call system, an engine optimization. A tail-call is when a function is called as the last statement in another function, like this:

```
function doSomething() {
    return doSomethingElse();   // tail call
}
```

ECMAScript 6 seeks to reduce the size of the call stack for certain tail calls in strict mode. With this optimization, **instead of creating a new stack frame for a tail call, the current stack frame is cleared and reused so long as the following conditions are met**:

1. strict mode must be turned on.
2. The tail call does not require access to variables in the current stack frame (meaning the function is not a closure).
3. The function making the tail call has no further work to do after the tail call returns.
4. The result of the tail call is returned as the function value.

> Perhaps the hardest situation to avoid is in using closures. Because a closure has access to variables in the containing scope, tail call optimization may be turned off. For example:

```
"use strict";

function doSomething() {
    var num = 1,
        func = () => num;

    // not optimized - function is a closure
    return func();
}
```

## Harness the TCO optimization:

Consider this function, which computes factorials:

```
"use strict";
function factorial(n) {

    if (n <= 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {

        // not optimized - must multiply after returning
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    }
}
```

In order to optimize the function, you need to ensure that the multiplication doesn’t happen after the last function call.

```
"use strict";
function factorial(n, p = 1) {

    if (n <= 1) {
        return 1 * p;
    } else {
        let result = n * p;

        // optimized
        return factorial(n - 1, result);
    }
}
```

**Source:** An *Awesome* book by Nicholas Zakas, Understanding ECMAScript 6.

Comment: I'm not sure why closures would prevent tco, is there any reason? I don't think it's in the spec either - tco should *always* happen. That the context needs to be preserved until the closure doesn't use it any more does not mean that the stack frame would need to stay around.

Comment: Free variables of closures are stored on the heap. So a closure can live longer than its surrounding scope, where it was declared. Consequently, closures don't interfere with TCO.

Comment: I indeed checked the spec and found nothing regarding closures, the source of my reply is from Nicholas Zakas's book, hence i asked him about it, hopefully i'll get a reply and update you.

Comment: Tq for your explanation but sorry about my question, it was on ES5,

Comment: @Sreevenkatesh es5 has no TCO optimization in the spec, some engines do some optimizations, some dont, its not a thing that you can control in es5. es6 is a little different that you have the exact recipe on how to opt in for it. use trampoline for es5, you will get a reliable optimization from it.

Comment: Then how to handle async calls in recursions. Trampoline handles only sync calls