# Why does JS have stack overflow issues with recursion?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, recursion, tail-recursion

**UPDATE:** It turns out in ECMAScript 6, you can enable tail call optimization using strict mode. Simply put 'use strict' at the top of the file and you're good to go.

I don't understand why the bubble sort function below has space complexity greater than 0(1). When I input a large array, I get a stack overflow error. Why is that?

```
//Bubble sort using recursion

var swapped = true

function swap(array, i, j) {
  var temp = array[i];
  array[i] = array[j];
  array[j] = temp;
}

function recursiveSwapping(arr, i = 0) {
  var len = arr.length;
  if (i >= len) {
    return arr
  }
  if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
    swap(arr, i, i + 1);
    swapped = true
  }
  return recursiveSwapping(arr, i + 1)
}

function recursiveBubbleSort(arr) {
  if (!swapped) {
    return arr
  }
    swapped = false
    recursiveSwapping(arr, i = 0)
    return recursiveBubbleSort(arr)
}
```

Comment: Each recursive call adds a stack frame. As your inputs get larger, so does the maximum stack depth the algorithm needs to reach.

Comment: I guess I don't understand how the call stack works then. For which variable does it need to remember previous states?

Comment: In this case, it doesn't actually *have* to remember anything, because your functions are all tail-recursive. Many functional languages do tail-call optimization, which solves exactly this problem (if memory serves, it's actually mandated by the Scheme spec), but it's not found in all languages. You can even see it more plainly by writing `function stackOverflow() {return stackOverflow();}`, which clearly keeps track of *nothing*!

Comment: Ah I see now. So there is no way to prevent stack overflow with recursive iteration?

Comment: apparently strict mode enables tail call optimization in ECMA6. I just learned that and it cleared up a lot.

Comment: E6 has TCO in spec, but there isn't one implementation that is 100% compliant so **there are no ES6 implementations at this time**. Safari has TCO as the only implementation I know of, but it lacks other ES6 features. Enabling strict mode doesn't imply TCO.

Comment: Here's an answer with more details about TCO in ES6: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562817/how-do-i-apply-tcotail-call-optimiztion-on-recursive-anonymous-function-in-es5/39563612#39563612

Comment: you can use the `setTimeout` trick to avoid this problem.